# Hyperlinks breaking when moving PDF in same Document Library in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, hyperlink, document-id, modern-document-library

hyperlinks keep breaking when moving a PDF between folders in same Document Library in SharePoint Online and show a blank screen when you click them. Tested this with Word, JPG, Excel and PowerPoint files and they do not have this issue, just PDFs.

When I check the console in the blank screen it shows "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (NOT FOUND)"

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To narrow down your issue:

1.Does only one user have similar issues?

2.What are the permissions of this user?

3.Has this issue occurred in other libraries?

4.Can this issue be reproduced stably? Or does it only appear once?

Comment: 1.Does only one user have similar issues?
I have it as a global admin and other users do too

2.What are the permissions of this user?
Global admin

3.Has this issue occurred in other libraries?
Yes, in all sites in that site collection

4.Can this issue be reproduced stably? Or does it only appear once?
Yes, it is always the same result. Word, jpegs, pngs, excel, powerpoint do not have this issue, only PDFS